# XQuery: Return value of an element rather the element itself

Tags: xml, xquery

I have an XML document that contains the following

```
...
<foo>abc</foo>
...
```

If I evaluate

```
return $xml//foo
```

I get back

```
<foo>abc</foo>
```

Is there any way to get just `abc` instead?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, you want the text() function for selecting the child text:

```
return $xml/text()
```

Be careful if you will have nested tag structure inside $xml though, because this will only go one level deep for text nodes. If you want all of the text nodes together, stripping out other XML structure, this will do arbitrarily deep:

```
return $xml//text()
```

Comment: text() is not a function.  It is a node test.  Before you go text() crazy, see Evan Lenz's post ["text() is a code smell"](http://developer.marklogic.com/blog/text-is-a-code-smell), as well as the Dave Cassel post I linked to below after Oliver's answer and Pavel's reply.

Answer (score 20):

Use the string function to get the string content of a node.

```
return string($xml)
```

Comment: This is actually a more idiomatic and better alternative than the preferred answer above. It will also handle any nesting of child nodes correctly.

Comment: Indeed.  See David Cassel's explanation of the [differences between text(), fn:string(), and fn:data()](http://blog.davidcassel.net/2011/06/text-fnstring-and-fndata/) -- all three of which have made appearances in the three answers so far.

Answer (score 9):

To return only the data inside an element you can use:

```
return data($xml)
```

Comment: More precisely, fn:data() is a function that gives you the atomized value of a node sequence, i.e., each node's typed value; whereas fn:string() gives you the string-value of a node.  See the links I've sprinkled through the comments above for more on the differences between text(), fn:string(), and fn:data().

Answer (score 0):

Cast to xs:string 
`{xs:string($xml/foo)}`

Answer (score 0):

OSB (oracle service bus) users can use following function.

`fn-bea:serialize($xml)`